# Variables to next activity

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity

I get 3 data string from editText (in 1 activity), and then go to next activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        a=editText.getText().toString();

        b=editText2.getText().toString();

        goToActivity2();
    }
});
```

and in 2 activity, i want to set new variables user1, user2, like this

```
public String user1 = a(from 1 activity);
public String user2 = b(from 1 activity);
```

Is it possible ? I cant found information about variables in my basics books java.

Comment: it is not duplicate

Comment: it **is** duplicate

Comment: read this http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html  it shows detailed approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass value of string to Activity2:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    String a = editText.getText().toString();
    String b = editText2.getText().toString();

   Intent intent = new Intent(your_activity.this, Activity2.class);
   intent.putExtra("a_value", a);
   intent.putExtra("b_value", b);
   startActivity(intent);
 }
});
```

Retrieve the value in 2nd Activity:

```
public String user1;
public String user2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
user1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("a_value");
user2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("b_value");
          ...........
                    ...........
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("a", a); --> a is variable, so what is "a" ?

Comment: error with this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.russian.app/ru.russian.app.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: when i write something in edittext and click the button, app still 'crash' with this same error ;/

Comment: now this error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.russian.app/ru.russian.app.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference

Comment: 1st block with code i put in onCreate() in 1Activity, 2 block of code with user1 and user 2 in 2Activity but over onCreate with other variables

Comment: but when i put this in onCreate, i cant use user1 and user2 in other method

Comment: 'public' is not allowed in onCreate()

Comment: when i try to put in onCreate() this: "public String user1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("a_value");" Androidstudio underlines 'public' and say "modifier 'public is not allowed here"

Comment: i still see old code "edited 1 hour ago"

Comment: Its edited, ago

Comment: you are awesome, all works, good luck in life!